# What should I use to add a String[1000][1000] to JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

As per the title.

I have a 2D array with size of 1000 x 1000.

I tried adding in to a gridpane and it went out of memory(haha...)
I am just wondering what would be the best way to go about this?

Requirements:

1) All container for the items in the array has to be of same size

2) I would like to show colour being applied to selected position of the 2D array.

---

Any guide to the right direction is greatly appreciated.
Really new to JavaFX.

*Contemplating canvas but...

Code:

```
private String[][] dataFromTxtFile;
GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();

private void initialize() {
        TextFileData txtFileData = new TextFileData();
        //txtFileData.getTxtFileData() gets a [1000][1000] array
        dataFromTxtFile = txtFileData.getTxtFileData();
        //Gridpane.add(dataon the box, column, row)
        for (int i =0; i<dataFromTxtFile.length;i++){
            for (int j=0; j<dataFromTxtFile[i].length;j++){
                Text data = new Text(dataFromTxtFile[i][j]);
                System.out.println("HERE: "+dataFromTxtFile[i][j]);
                gridpane.add(data,i,j);
            }
        }
}
```

I am trying to display the data on a 1000 x 1000 grid.
The items in it are just numbers.

Comment: You want to have a million items displayed in your GUI? At the same time?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Please edit your question to describe the ultimate objective in detail.

Comment: In detail is just I want to display a [1000][1000] data (yes. its 1 million) onto a 1000 by 1000 grid. The data is numbers for now. Later on will be colouring the grid of a selected index/grid (eg: at [50][150], colour the grid as green)

Comment: If you have a physical screen capable of displaying all (or at least a large proportion) of these at once, you just need to drive it with a computer with enough memory to keep a million UI components in memory. If you are going to embed this in a scroll pane of some kind, you need to implement a virtual component. Doing that from scratch is beyond the scope of an SO question, but you might look at Tomas Mikula's [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless) for ideas. You would need a two-dimensional version of that.

Comment: @James_D, wow. Thanks. That looks promising. Will try it out :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are only storing numbers, use an Array of ints. It might still be not enough memory, but ints take up less memory than strings. Use `Integer.parseInt("string")` to convert from string to int.

Comment: I agree. But the data I input is jz a random int for now. However, the data is taken from a txt file in a specific format which could be strings as well. Thats why I just want to know what other controls that javafx has that can do this